# Finding Games folder?

Tags: steam, pc, origin

So I want to add my Dragon Age: Origins game to my Steam Library. However, when I open up the "Add a Game" explorer window for adding a non-steam game, I cannot for the life of me find DA:O!

The only address my computer says the Dragon Age: Origins .exe file is in "Games". But I **CAN'T** seem to find how to navigate to the Games Explorer within the Steam explorer! How do I get to Games using the explorer??

Comment: This seems like it should be tagged [Origin], not [Steam], because it's about finding the file location of an Origin game, not a Steam game.

Comment: Done and done. I just labeled it as Steam because I was trying to add it to my Steam Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do.

Head to this location on your computer, I assume that in installed your game on the C drive: C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Dragon Age\bin_ship

Once you are there, locate the file called daorigins.exe, this is your launcher file.

now you just need to paste the path of the folder mentionned earlier to your Steam Explorer and select daorigins.exe.

I hope that helps!

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The only location it gives for Origins is the Games Explorer. That's it!

Comment: Are you able to locate the folder containing your game's .exe without using the Steam explorer?

Comment: No I am not. The only way I am able to get to it is searching for it with the Start Menu, and then right clicking "Open File Location". It takes me to the Games Explorer.

Comment: And you are able to see your game's .exe there right?

Comment: Yes, in the list of other games. But I can't right-click and see the Properties of it. Link: http://pbrd.co/1si4nW4

Comment: Ok I see the problem. I will edit my answer soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17758/discussion-between-thebird956-and-guy).

Comment: Adding games from the 'games explorer' is tricky.  I had a similar issue when I tried to add Bionic Commando Rearmed, and Homebrew.